# jQuery detached element gets duplicated when reattached?

Tags: jquery

I have this code for removing (detaching) a submenu from a menu item and attach it after the header (don't ask; it's WP and WPML, yeah the general mess) for better control of styling etc.:

```
    $('li.wpml-ls-current-language > a').on('click', function ( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let retachTo = $( this ).parent();

        let sub_menu = $('ul.sub-menu');

        if ( ! sub_menu.is(':visible') ) {
            sub_menu.addClass('show').detach();
            $('header').after( sub_menu );
        } else {
            sub_menu.removeClass('show').detach();
            retachTo.append( sub_menu );
        }
    })
```

Now, the submenu gets duplicated exponentially everytime I click the menu item. I don't know if this is due to exhaustion or the like, but I can't seem to figure out WHERE the duplicate comes from.

Can anyone spot what it is that I'm missing completely?

Comment: Can you share the URL of the website?

Comment: Localhost; not publically available, unfortunately. But that's basically the functionallity.

The problem is the duplicate – now, WHERE would it come from?

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to play around with it, but perhaps `$('ul.sub-menu')` is selecting multiple `<ul>` elements?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. But I can assure you that's not the case. I've got only one ul.sub-menu (which is WHY it bugs me in the first place). But, I had to go with another solution rather than this DOM shuffling – which to me seem like a way to unstable way to solve these kind of issues.